# Phoengap app Application Error on startup

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am developing a android phoenegap application. Thanks to the Stackoverflow, I managed to get it to start working. Only issue is with the timeout. The app sometimes start smoothly without throwing error, but sometime it throws error:

`Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful. 
(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)`

I googled and found 2 solutions:

1)Add timeout value: super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 10000);

2)Create a dummy index page as in [this link](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/app_dies_on_startup_connection_to_the_server_was_unsuccessful)

But still the problem not solved. I have also tried increasing the timeout from 10000 to 100000. Still no help. The emulator sometimes seems to work fine but suddenly agin throws the same error.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>First App</title>
    <style> 
        .table {
        border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
        background: #dddddd;
        width: 90px;
        height: 90px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        position:absolute;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function onLoad()
    {
        $('.table1').html('');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://192.168.0.70:81/MobileService.asmx/GetTables",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (msg) {
            var Tabels = msg.d;
            $.each(Tabels, function(index, table) {
                alert('ptx'+table.PointX);
                var tabel_data='<div class="table"';
                tabel_data +=' style="top:'+ table.PointY +'px;';
                tabel_data +='left:'+table.PointX+'px;"';
                tabel_data +=">"+table.TableName +"</div>";
                $('.table1').append(tabel_data);
            });
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error');
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="submit" onclick="onLoad();" value="layout1">
    <div class="table1" style="position: absolute; display: block;" ></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

about your Application Error:

1. Are you developing using the PhoneGap Developer App?
2. Are you using the deviceready event as the primary hook in your application?

I would advise against a static (10 second!) timeout, there are better ways which don't impact the usability of your app. A dummy index is similarly hacky. If you can give me more info I'm sure we can work this out for you.

I believe your problem is likely number 2: attempting to interact with cordova api's before deviceready fires

Comment: I am using eclipse to develop. And no I have not used on deviceready event. I am doing my stuff on click of a button. I will post my index.html page for your reference.

Comment: I tried with on deviceready, it is working now. Thanks @Lorenzo for the help. How can I handle on click event?

Comment: you can see an example in the phonegap hello world app:https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-hello-world/blob/master/www/js/index.js. Remember to accept/upvote the answer if it helped. If you want a more comprehensive answer, you could search for online tutorials, or search/start another question